# Writting XSL-t in a XSL FO document

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm a beginner at XSL FO.
I have a very simple XML document :

```
<?xml version= "1.0" ?>
<test>
TEST
</test>
```

I would like to print the content between the tag `<test>`

I wrote the following XLS FO document to be processed by FOP.

```
<fo:root xmlns:yt="http://www.yseop.com/text/2" 
xmlns:y="http://www.yseop.com/engine/3" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rapport">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="0.75in" margin-left="0.75in" margin-right="0.75in" margin-bottom="0.75in"/>
         <fo:region-after extent="0.25in"/>
         <fo:region-start/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>

   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="rapport">

       <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
            XXX
                <xsl:apply-templates select="document('D:\XXX-conseilVente\xmlBatch\input_test1.xml')/test"/>
            </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>



</fo:root>
```

I get the following warning :

```
      [fop] 25 mai 2011 12:05:10 org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
      [fop] ATTENTION: Unknown formatting object "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform}apply-templates" encountered (a child of fo:block}. (See position 22:99)
```

and there is nothing on my output pdf.

I guess I am not using the right function to parse the document with xsl-t

Can you tell me what function to use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSLT and XSL-FO are two separate languages. Basically, it works the other way round, than what you do at the moment: The FO is embedded in an XSLT stylesheet, which is then used to process the original XML to create an XSL-FO document (without any XSLT). That is thrown at the XSL-FO processor to create, e.g., PDF.

```
    XSLT     processing
     |           |
XML ---> XSL-FO ---> PDF
```

So you start with a XSLT stylesheet like this (no namespaces and such, just to give you an idea):

```
<xslt:stylesheet>

  <xslt:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <!-- fo head -->
      <fo:page-sequence>
        <fo:flow>
          <xslt:apply-templates /> <!-- process the rest of the doc-->
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xslt:template>

  <xslt:template match="test">
    <fo:block>
      <xslt:value-of select="." />
    </fo:block>
  </xslt:template>

</xslt:stylesheet>
```

You can find many questions ansered at [Dave Pawson's XSL FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/index.html).